# Как передать переменную id='имя(переменная цифра)' в js #имя(переменная цифра) код

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код *javascript*

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#application[цифра]").click(function(event){
       $('#applicationModal[цифра]').arcticmodal(); 
    });
});
</script>
```

и *php*

```
echo "<div style='display: none;'>
    <div class='box-modal' id='applicationModal".$row['id']."'>
        <div class='box-modal_close arcticmodal-close'>закрыть</div>
        Пример модального окна c id ".$row['id']."
    </div>
</div>";
echo "<td width='100'><div id='tablelinks'><a href='#' class='button21' id='application".$row['id']."' tabindex='0'>кнопка</a></div>";
```

В *php* формируется `id='applicationModal1'`, `id='applicationModal2'` и таких блоков много.

Как обозначить в коде *javascript* переменную цифру?

Код из браузера. Все блоки идентичны только меняется конечная цифра в id

```
 <div style='display: none;'>
        <div class='box-modal' id='applicationModal8'>
            <div class='box-modal_close arcticmodal-close'>закрыть</div>
            Пример модального окна c id 8
        </div>
    </div><td width='100'><div id='tablelinks'><a href='#' class='button21' id='application8' tabindex='0'>кнопка</a></div>
```

Comment: Обычно в таких случаях используют либо поиск предка, либо атрибут `data-*`. Можно, конечно, костыльком кривоногим решить, но это кашрут запрещает :)

Comment: а что мешает использовать делегирование в jquery ? А потом узнавать цифру то объекту с атрибута например data-number ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привязывать одно и тоже событие к пачке разных элементов по ID - не лучшее решение. Если у вас несколько элементов должны вести себя одинаково - у них должен быть одинаковый класс (например, `modal-trigger`). Проставьте его всем элементам. Потом проставьте им разный data-аттрибут с индексом модального окна (например, `data-modal-number`). И навесьте на всех их один обработчик:

```js
$(function(){
    $(".modal-trigger").click(function(){
      // this в этом обработчике - это элемент, на который кликнули
      var modalNumber =  $(this).data("modal-number");
      alert(modalNumber);
      $("#applicationModal" + modalNumber).arcticmodal(); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class='modal-trigger' data-modal-number='1'>show modal 1</a>
<a href="#" class='modal-trigger' data-modal-number='2'>show modal 2</a>
```

По хорошему и поиск applicationModalX по id стоит убрать, но это уже на ваше усмотрение.

Comment: а стоит ли например на 30 объектов вешать обработчик? 
Можно ведь добавить общую обертку и делегировать через нее.

Comment: @MaksDevda какие преимущества вы в этом видите?

Comment: @Regent 
Первое: если динамически добавлять блоки - то Ваш код не сработает на новых элементах.
Второе: если элементов будет много - Ваш подход снизить производительность в силу большого количества обработчиков.

Comment: @MaksDevda во первых это не его код, а мой. Во вторых - всегда можно напридумывать всяких "если". Чтобы производительность упала, элементов должно быть МНОГО. И кликать на них при этом надо очень часто, непереставая. Стоит ли на 30 элементов вешать onclick обработчик - да. [In most cases, an event such as click occurs infrequently and performance is not a significant concern](http://api.jquery.com/on/). И не факт что `.on` на `document` будет быстрее. Скорее наоборот. "Если динамически добавлять блоки" - у топикастера они добавляются динамически? Нет - значит тупо click хватит с головой.

Comment: @PashaPash все верно, но мы же стремимся к идеальности кода. Одна поправка: .on не нужно вешать на документ, только на wrapper какой то.

Comment: @MaksDevda Вешать на враппер - да не может быть! вы открыли мне глаза! :) Я не стремлюсь к идеальности кода. Код должен решать проблему, а не быть идеальным. Если вас что-то не устраивает в моем ответе - напишите свой. Подробно объясните в нем в каких случаях надо вешать delegated events, а в каких - не надо. Заодно серверный код перепишите в нормальном виде. Я это за вас делать не обязан. Вобщем, займитесь делом, а не учите меня основам jquery, ок?

Answer (score 0):

Первый способ:
Если код JS находится на странице, которая формируется PHP, то можно прямо в него и выводить переменную

```
echo "
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#application[цифра]").click(function(event){
       $('#applicationModal[".$row['id']."]').arcticmodal(); 
    });
});
</script>";
```

Второй способ:
Хранить переменную в скрытом `<input type='hidden' value='переменная цифра' id='aaa'>`
А в JS уже вытягивать эту переменную, обращаясь к элементу #aaa